# How can I get unique pairs using BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table. I'm getting all possible pairs using `CROSS JOIN`. How can I filter unique ones only?
`CROSS JOIN` returns all combos of ids. For example 101 and 102 as well as 102 and 101. How can I reduce all inversed doubles keeping first getting pair (101 and 102) using BigQuery?

```
    with t0 as (SELECT 1 as big_id, '101' as small_id,  0.99 as bottom, 1.03 top
      UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'z3Awwer', 1.05, 1.09
      UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'gA1sd03', 1.09, 1.13
      UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'sAs10sdf4', 1.2, 1.25
      UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'Adf105', 1.33, 1.39
      UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'A1sdf02', 1.05, 1.09
      UNION ALL SELECT 2, '345A103', 1.09, 1.13
      UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'A1sd04', 1.2, 1.25
      UNION ALL SELECT 2, '6_0Awe105', 1.33, 1.39)
SELECT * FROM t0
CROSS JOIN t0 t1 
WHERE t0.big_id = t1.big_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is based on real data, but you could add a filter to drop out small_id's that have already been joined:

```
SELECT *
FROM t0
CROSS JOIN t0 t1 
WHERE t0.big_id = t1.big_id
  and t1.small_id >= t0.small_id
```

This ensures that 101 will show up with a 102, but 102 will not show up with a 101.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Unfortunately, small id is `STRING` in real data

Comment: Edited to cast `small_id` as an integer.

Comment: Sometimes id has charters

Comment: Then why didn't you accept the original answer?  You can still compare strings: `select 'A102' >= 'A101'` will be true while `select 'A101' >= 'A102'` will be false.  The added filter should still be valid.  Using your dataset, the result set is reduced from 41 results to 25 when you apply the filter.

Comment: Unclear what you are looking for.  My answer still eliminates small_id/small_id_1 dupes.